# How can we generate html report by using jenkins console log count of pass and fail?

Tags: xslt, selenium, jenkins, reporting

I am running a job through Jenkins and want to generate an Html report for the count of pass and fail displayed in the console log of Job in jenkins.

How can I generate an html report for this?

Answer (score 0):

To add reports , you should implement the report or use the testNg report.

1) for testNg report, you no need to write code, you just need to configure in Jenkins as like below

2) for our own reports, you should implement Ireporter interface and add that in tetsNg

[image]

Comment: Thanks Raghav also please let me know that how can I implement Ireporter interface with jenkins. It would very helpful if you can provide some information or steps to implement it with jenkins.